# integrating small angular velocities

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotation, angular-velocity

I know that for a constant angular velocity the following is true:
$R=e^{W t} R_0$
where $W$ is an angular velocity tensor, $t$ is a time, and $R$ is a rotation matrix

I believe the following is approximately true for small rotations:
$R=e^{(W_1+W_2) t} R_0 \approx e^{W_1 t} e^{W_2 t} R_0 \approx e^{W_2 t} e^{W_1 t} R_0$

Can anyone point me toward a proof (or disproof) of the above statement?

Thank you.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential) suggests that the distribution of $t$ to $W_1$ and $W_2$ is proper, but reversing the order of multiplication of the two exponentials only works if $W_1W_2=W_2W_1$

Comment: in general $W_1 W_2 = W_2 W_1$ is not true for skew-symmetric matrices, however. according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#The_exponential_of_sums) $AB=BA$ is a sufficient but not necessary condition for $e^{(A+B)}=e^A e^B$

Comment: and to be clear, I'm hypothesizing that this only holds for "small" $W t$

Comment: for "sufficiently small" rotations/timesteps, $W_1 \approx W_2$

Comment: i think that is not true. for example:
$$W_1=[0, 0, 0; 0, 0, -1; 0, 1, 0](1e^{-6})$$  
$$W_2=[0, 0, 1; 0, 0, 0; -1, 0, 0](1e^{-6})$$
$W_1 W_2$ is very different from $W_2 W_1$

Comment: that's right. I was imagining that $W_2 = W_1 + \alpha t$, for some angular acceleration tensor $\alpha$, not as a different rotation

Comment: no, i meant very different but small velocity tensors